# spring batch restart job starts from initial stage instead of where it left off?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to implement the functionality of restart job to start it from initial sage. I am facing two issues.

First Problem: When I restart the job very first time it will create a new job instance id and behave like a fresh job. In the second time, it will restart and run with same job instance id. (I sent the execution id from rest controller)

Second Problem: It will start from the initial stage when I will restart it.

Custom Reader:

```
package com.orange.alc.dabekdataload.reader;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.annotation.AfterStep;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.annotation.BeforeStep;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStream;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.NonTransientResourceException;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.UnexpectedInputException;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
    import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import com.orange.alc.dabekdataload.constants.PostalHeader;
    import com.orange.alc.dabekdataload.dto.PostalDto;

    @Component("itemReader")
    @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public class PostalReader implements ItemReader<PostalDto>, ItemStream{

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostalReader.class);

        @Value("#{jobParameters[fullPathFileName]}")
        public String fileName;

        private int currentIndex = 0;

        private static final String CURRENT_INDEX = "current.index";

        private FlatFileItemReader<PostalDto> reader;

        @BeforeStep
        public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            LOGGER.info("Executing batch reader...");
            reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
            reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(fileName));
            reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
            reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<PostalDto>() {{
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                    setNames(PostalHeader.getPostalColumnNames());
                }});
                setFieldSetMapper(new PostalFieldSetMapper());
            }});
            reader.setSaveState(true);
            reader.open(stepExecution.getExecutionContext());

        }

        @Override
        public PostalDto read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
            reader.setCurrentItemCount(currentIndex++);
           return reader.read();
        }

        @AfterStep
        public void afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
            LOGGER.info("Closing the reader...");
            reader.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
            if(executionContext.containsKey(CURRENT_INDEX)){
                currentIndex = new Long(executionContext.getLong(CURRENT_INDEX)).intValue();
            } else{
                currentIndex = 0;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
            executionContext.putLong(CURRENT_INDEX, new Long(currentIndex).longValue());

        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws ItemStreamException {


        }


    }
```

Job Restart Code:

```
@Override
public void restartJob(Long jobId) throws JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, NoSuchJobExecutionException, NoSuchJobException, JobRestartException, JobParametersInvalidException {
    LOGGER.info("Restarting job with JobId: {}", jobId);
    jobOperator.restart(jobId);
}
```

Please let me know in case you need any code from my side.

Answer (score 1):

The delegate reader (`FlatFileItemReader`) used in your custom reader (`PostalReader`) is not honouring the `ItemStream` contract. You need to call `open/update/close` on the delegate reader in the corresponding `open/update/close` methods of your item reader. Something like:

```
public class PostalReader implements ItemReader<PostalDto>, ItemStream{

   private FlatFileItemReader<PostalDto> reader;

   @Override
   public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
      reader.open(executionContext);
   }

   @Override
   public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
      reader.update(executionContext);
   }

   @Override
   public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
      reader.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mahmoud the second problem resolved after the implementation as you suggested. Can you please let me know how can I resolved the second problem.

Comment: `It will start from the initial stage when I will restart it.`: Not sure I understand this. This means you start a new instance. Restarting from initial stage makes no sense to me.

Comment: Suppose I run the job and It is failed with execution id "1" and instance id "1". Now I restart the job with execution id "1" it is failed with execution id "2" and instance id "2". Now again I restart the job with execution id ''1" Now it failed with execution id "3" and instance id "2". Due to this first-time restart behave like the fresh job because the new instance is created. But second time when job instance is same it performs like a restart.

Comment: Expected Behaviour:- Suppose I run the job and It is failed with execution id "1" and instance id "1". Now I restart the job with execution id "1" it is failed with execution id "2" and instance id "1"

Comment: `Suppose I run the job and It is failed with execution id "1" and instance id "1". Now I restart the job with execution id "1" it is failed with execution id "2" and instance id "2".`: That's is not correct, if execution 1 failed for instance 1, then when you restart it, you will have execution 2 for instance 1 **not instance 2** (same when you restart execution 2 if it fails, it will still instance 1 **not instance 3**). Please check https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/domain.html#domainLanguageOfBatch where these concepts are explained in details.

Comment: Thanks, Mahmoud but I fixed that issue. It is because of job parameters. I used new  Date() as a job parameter to run the job. But I found that MySQL has some round-off issue with the date. Anyone facing the same issue can look into the link http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/66340-restart-job-same-parameters-caused-new-jobinstance-in-db

Answer (score 0):

The update method from itemStream will put the exeuctionContext in current Step's execution context. But when you restart the job, the step re run as a new step and it cannot get the execution context of previous step. In order to start processing the data from where it left for restart, you need to save the state in job execution context.